# Duplicate class error "Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbl"

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin, google-play-services

I'm working on incorporating some beacon technology SDKs in our React Native app, and I'm running into some build issues as I do so. They seem unrelated, so I'm confused as to what brought these issues up.

Below is the error spit out from Android Studio during an attempted build and install on a real device:

`Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbl found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbn found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbo found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbp found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzbr found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zze found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzg found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzi found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkf found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkh found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzki found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkj found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzkl found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-face-contour-internal-16.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-face-contour-internal:16.0.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzv found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0) Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules jetified-play-services-vision-20.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.0.0) and jetified-play-services-vision-common-19.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision-common:19.1.0)`

I've seen this fix: [How to solve this error : Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.vision.zzw found in modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443018/how-to-solve-this-error-duplicate-class-com-google-android-gms-internal-vision) but this did not resolve my issues.

If needed, I can include my build.gradle versions but I thought this block of text was already too massive.